# Incorrect answer from #define SQR(x) (x*x)

Tags: c

The following program is printing `49`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SQR(x) (x*x) 
void main(void) { 
    int x, y; x = 5; 
    y = SQR(++x); 
    printf("y is %d\n", y); 
}
```

I don't understand what I am missing.
Here is what I am understanding how it might be working
In `SQR(++x)`,  `++x` will be evaluated to be `6` and after `x*x` the `36` should be returned.
Therefore `y = 36`
But the answer is **49**

Comment: Think about how macros work and how many times the expression is evaluated.

Comment: @Matt: nah, it's not Undefined per se.

Comment: @Matt: ah I get it -- the execution order of both `++x`'s is not known...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the wikipage about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) and understand that the C preprocessor operate at a purely textual level (as the first phase of the compiler). Read also [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) documentation. Your `y = SQR(++x);`is expanded as

```
y = ++x * ++x;
```

Which is not what you should want. Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)).
Think about the horror happening (using your original `SQR`)  with `SQR(y+3)`.

Look at the preprocessed form of your source code. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), use

```
gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i
```

to obtain into `foo.i` (which you should examine with an editor or a pager) the preprocessed form of `foo.c`

So, at the very least, you should define your macro as

```
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Otherwise `SQR(y+3)` won't be expanded like you want. In general when using a macro you should know (and document, e.g. in a comment, if you are writing the macro) what is happening.

In fact, in your case, you should not use a macro at all, but define an [inline function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)

```
static inline int square(int x) { return x*x; }
```

this would be as fast as your macro, but much more safe, since `square(++x)` would increment (rightly) `x` only once, and `square(y+3)` is doing what you want!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that macros are replaced pretty much verbatim, that means your

```
SQR(++x);
```

will be replaced by

```
++x * ++x;
```

And, as noted by dyp, it's undefined behavior.